# Using two RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have two RewriteRule in my .htaccess file which is hosted at godaddy.First one is for redirecting http to https and works fine.Second one is for using slash instead of question marks in URL but not working.Where am I wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sosyosapien.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^low/$ https://www.sosyosapien.com/index.php?postt=$1&konu=$2&kategori=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Edit:To be more clear,my URL now looks like :

`sosyosapien.com/index.php?postt=23&konu=what_is_sosyosapien&kategori=science`

But I want it to look like

```
sosyosapien.com/index.php/23/what_is_sosyosapien/science
```

But my code only does http to https redirect and cant change the URL in the way I want.Sorry I dont have enough knowledge of .htaccess' working principle.Can you please give me a code to do what I need?

Comment: In the second rewrite you have groups $1-3 which are not matched on the left (only low/ in pattern). If you need redirect it too add R=301 in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely do not want to add this RewriteRule to your `.htaccess`. It is incorrect and it is missing capturing groups that it has been referred to:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^low/$ https://www.sosyosapien.com/index.php?postt=$1&konu=$2&kategori=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

If you really have to keep this, you might find out what <kbd>$1</kbd>, <kbd>$2</kbd> and <kbd>$3</kbd> are that you might want to redirect. Then, you could change this `^low/$` based on that.

---

Maybe, just add this, and it might work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sosyosapien\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sosyosapien.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} postt=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.php\?postt=([0-9]+)&konu=(\w+)&kategori=(\w+)$ ^$1\/$2\/$3\/$4$ [R,L,302]


</IfModule>
```

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/HBKZp5/1) might help you to simplify your expression, as you wish, since I'm not sure what types of conditions you might have:

```
^(.*)\/index\.php\?postt=([0-9]+)&konu=(\w+)&kategori=(\w+)$
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the RegEx works:

[image]

- You might need to restart apache:

  ```
     sudo apachectl restart
  ```
- You also want to clear your browser cache, every time that you would make a change in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Sir unfortunately,it didnt work for me.It still only does the redirection and doesnt change the URL structure.I edited my question to be more clear,can you please check it out...